# Residues of $ f(z)=\frac{1}{z} \sin(\frac{1}{1-z} ) $

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, laurent-series

I'm having a little trouble, calculating the residues of $ f(z)=\frac{1}{z} \sin(\frac{1}{1-z} ) $ at $z=0$ and $z=1$.

As for the residue at $z=0$, it can easily be calculated since $0$ is a simple pole of $f$, we have :
$Res(f,1)=\lim_{z\to 0} zf(z)=\sin(1)$

However, it seems to me that there are two ways to calculate the residue of $f$ at $1$ :

If I calculate the Laurent Series of f, I get one answer :
With $u=z-1$

$$ f(z)= \frac{1}{1+u}\sin(\frac{-1}{u})= (-1) \times (\sum_{n=0}^{\infty  }{(-1)^n u^n}) \times (\sum_{n=0}^{\infty  }{\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}u^{-n}})$$

Thus, the residue is equal to the $u^{-1}$ coefficient : $$ (-1) \times \sum_{n=0}^{\infty  }{(-1)^n \times \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(2n+3)!} }=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty  }{ \frac{1}{(2n+3)!} }   =    \sum_{n=0}^{\infty  }{ \frac{1}{(2n+1)!} } - 1 = \sin(-1)-1 \\= -1-\sin(1)$$

Thus, by calculating the Laurent series, I get : $Res(f,1) = -1-\sin(1)$

However, through the residue theorem, I get another answer :

If we consider  the circle of radius $R>1$, centered in $1$, then through the residue theorem : $$ \int_{C_ R}{f(z)\,dz} = 2i\pi(Res(f,0) + Res(f,1)) $$

Furthermore, since $ \lim_{|z|\to\infty} zf(z) =0 $ , through Jordan's lemma, we get : $$ Res(f,0) + Res(f,1) =   \frac{1}{2i\pi}  \times   \lim_{R\to\infty}  \int_{C_ R}{f(z)\,dz}=0 $$

Therefore : $ Res(f,1)=-Res(f,0)=-\sin(1) $

I seem to get two different answers, and I don't see where I made a mistake. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I'd be tempted to write : $  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty  }{\frac{1}{(2n+3)!}  }   =   \sum_{n=1}^{\infty  }{\frac{1}{(2n+1)!}  } = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty  }{\frac{1}{(2n+1)!}  } -  \frac{1}{(2\times 0+1)!}  =  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty  }{\frac{1}{(2n+1)!}  } - 1 $ . Is there an error here ?

Comment: nope @sku this is correct, $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac1{(2n+3)!} = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac1{(2(n+1)+1)!} = \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac1{(2n+1)!} = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac1{(2n+1)!} - 1$.

Comment: I am sorry. I dont know what I was thinking,,,

Comment: your series for the sine is wrong, its not $u^{-n}$, it must be $u^{-2n-1}$

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comment the error in your computation is in the expansion of the sine function. With a correct expansion of the sine we get:

$$
\begin{align*}
\frac1{z}\sin \left(\frac1{1-z}\right)&=-\frac1{1+(z-1)}\sin \left(\frac1{z-1}\right)\\
&=-\sum_{k\geqslant 0}(-1)^k(z-1)^k \sum_{j\geqslant 0}(-1)^j\frac{(z-1)^{-2j-1}}{(2j+1)!}
\end{align*}
$$

Therefore the coefficient for $(z-1)^{-1}$ is given by

$$
-\sum_{k\geqslant 0}(-1)^{2k}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!}=-\sum_{k\geqslant 0}(-1)^{k}\frac{1^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}=-\sin (1)
$$
∎